# how to access arraylist sent from server in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement of displaying a `dropdown` list based on the `arraylist` being sent from the server on certain conditions  on load of the page and on change of the event
For example 
`ArrayList1`,`ArrayList2`

```
 if(condition is true)

 display the contents to dropdownlist from arraylist1

else

 display the contents to dropdownlist from arraylist 2
```

Can any one tel how this arraylist can be saved on the page as hidden field so i can access the same in javascript.
??

Comment: Server, you say? Care to tell us a little more about it? The code that creates the page? The platform? Anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the array you could do somthing like this:

```
 <form>
    <select id="my_seelecyt">
    </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var list1=['a','b','c'];
    var list2=['e','f','g'];
    var list;
    var select_box = document.getElementById('my_seelecyt');
    if(condition is true){
        list=list1;
    }else{
        list=list2;
    }
    for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
        var op = document.createElement('option');
        op.value=list[i];
        op.innerHTML =  list[i];
        select_box.appendChild(op);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to options:

- Using ajax to create a request to the server and store the response in a variable I. e. the js-framework jquery allows you to make a post request and get it back)
- Using a server side technology like php, jsp, asp to put the response into a javascript variable

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that you pre-generate the drop-down lists and then toggle that in JS based on some criteria, then this is how it could be done:

First generate HTML:

```
<div id="arraylist1" style="display:none">
  <select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="arraylist2" style="display:none">
  <select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!-- This is the placeholder for the dropdown -->
<div id="list"></div>
```

And then use this in JavaScript:

```
var arrayList = condition ? $('div#arrayList1') : $('div#arrayList2');
$('#list').append(arrayList);
arrayList.show();
```